# AWS Batch job is marked as successful when in fact its log shows that it failed

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services

I have a job in AWS Batch, which calls a .sh file which in turn executes a python script. The python script fails with an error that it does not find a specific file in a directory, but, the process in AWS Batch finishes successfully, which should be the other way around. Is there anything I should check?

Comment: Your shell script will exit with the status of the last command it runs unless you explicitly exit with a code. Is the python script the last thing your shell script executes?

Comment: hello, no, then come some echo's.

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see both of the scripts for a better understanding. But unless you have some specific catch exception methods in your python script to return an error to the shell script when faced with an error, your shell script will proceed to run normally even if your python script returns an error.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 main.py # calls a python script
                # python script returns an error
echo "Hellow World!" # The shell script does not know if your python script returned an error or not.
                # So it continues running the shell script
```

So the output would most likely be something like below:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python-stuff
Hello World!
```

Comment: Exactly, that's what happens! just as you say. How could I fix it? you know? Thanks!

Comment: you could add [try and exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to your python script so that it retries or do whatever you want it to when it failes to find the file. It really depends on what you want it to do if it fails, rather than just "how to fix". if you wanna fix it, make sure its facing toward the correct directory?

Comment: thanks for your answer, first of all I should direct it to the correct directory, but beyond that I would like the aws batch to fail and not to mark it as success, because the same thing happened to me once when I tried to insert data in postgres (also from a .py file), the database was down but the batch process didn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing along the exit status:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /path/to/script.py
exit $?
```

Comment: Okey, I did it and returns a 1.

Comment: That means the script isn't running correctly so you should review the setup and usage of AWS Batch  https://github.com/ryerkerk/aws-batch-python-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Add `set -euxo pipefail` in the first line after the shebang of your bash script and it will fail if any of your statements fail.

More information [here](https://gist.github.com/mohanpedala/1e2ff5661761d3abd0385e8223e16425) about what those set flags mean.

Actually to solve your question just `set -e` could be enough in some cases, but the other additional flags are also nice to have in most cases (as in the example below which does not fail just with `set -e`, you need `set -eu`).

One example script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euxo pipefail
echo $UNDECLARED VARIABLE
echo "Script does not reach here"
```

If you run above script you will get this error: `UNDECLARED: unbound variable`. However without `set -euxo pipefail` script will exit with success error code (`echo $?` will return zero because the last statement was executed without errors).